# Understanding of CPU seconds

Tags: python, profile, cpu-usage

consider following example:

```
import hotshot
import hotshot.stats
import time

def test_sleep():
    time.sleep(1)

def main():
    prof = hotshot.Profile("lol.prof")
    prof.runcall(test_sleep)
    prof.close()

    stats = hotshot.stats.load("lol.prof")
    stats.sort_stats("time", "calls")
    stats.print_stats(20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I got this output:

```
debian:# python lol.py
         1 function calls in 1.000 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000 lol.py:6(test_sleep)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```

I expect that I will have 0sec CPU time and 1sec wall time.

I expect 1 CPU second in case of busy loop, not in case of sleep.

Can someone explain why I get such results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a HotShot bug -- it's not getting CPU time from the OS, it's getting elapsed time (and maybe subtracting out I/O wait time, which would be zero in this case).  If you do `time python lol.py` you'll see that you're not in a busy wait.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere? I got same results with cProfile. "time python.lol" works fine.